# What is the correct location for db object initialization?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, architecture

I am building a plugin for WordPress 3.3.1. In the code I define several shortcodes, class to support them, and a couple of admin pages. I am at a beginners level with php although I have 20+ years experience with programming, OOA&D, etc..

In the class methods, I make calls to a custom database not housed in the wp database. That is, the custom database is a separate schema, independent of the wp database.

Right now, I make the declaration in the methods that need the object. Works fine for dev but won't cut it in production. I am tempted to raise it to the class instance level. Here is where my question becomes clear. There are several classes that will need the connection. The plugin needs only one connection.

Where is the best place to put the database connection object declaration and initialization?

Given the answer to that, where is the proper place to destroy the db connection object instance?

Comment: WP is known to be a big ball of mud. There is no architecture. There is just one hackable mess of spaghetti and ravioli. So in this rare case no kittens will die if you use a Singleton Db class. You dont need to destroy it. It will get purged at the end of the request anyway.

Comment: This might be of interest: [WordPress Plugin: How do I avoid “tight coupling”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8688738/367456)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I would make the database connection a static field. Which class to put it in depends on how you've structured your classes/code. Making it `static` will ensure that the same connection is shared throughout your script.
- I recommend using PDO [(connecting PDO to MySQL, etc)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) to connect to your database. PHP will automatically close the connection when the script ends.

Comment: I thought PDO was deprecated in deference to wsdb. Anyway, the STATIC approach seems to work just fine, placed at the top of the script first called by WP.